# what part of app should be in service?

Tags: android

I am using the periodic location updates and wanted to know which part should be put in service so that even when the app is closed it keeps running. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private TextView mLatLng;
private TextView mConnectionState;
private TextView mConnectionStatus;
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLatLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_lng);
    mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_connection_state);
    mConnectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_connection_status);

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest
            .setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest
            .setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mUpdatesRequested = false;
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        stopPeriodicUpdates();
    }
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mEditor.putBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED,
            mUpdatesRequested);
    mEditor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // If the app already has a setting for getting location updates, get it
    if (mPrefs.contains(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED)) {
        mUpdatesRequested = mPrefs.getBoolean(
                LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);

        // Otherwise, turn off location updates until requested
    } else {
        mEditor.putBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {

    // Choose what to do based on the request code
    switch (requestCode) {

    // If the request code matches the code sent in onConnectionFailed
    case LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:

        switch (resultCode) {
        // If Google Play services resolved the problem
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:

            // Log the result
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.resolved));

            // Display the result
            mConnectionState.setText(R.string.connected);
            mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.resolved);
            break;

        // If any other result was returned by Google Play services
        default:
            // Log the result
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.no_resolution));

            // Display the result
            mConnectionState.setText(R.string.disconnected);
            mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.no_resolution);

            break;
        }

        // If any other request code was received
    default:
        // Report that this Activity received an unknown requestCode
        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                getString(R.string.unknown_activity_request_code,
                        requestCode));

        break;
    }
}

private boolean servicesConnected() {

    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                getString(R.string.play_services_available));

        // Continue
        return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
    } else {
        // Display an error dialog
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,
                this, 0);
        if (dialog != null) {
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
            errorFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void getLocation(View v) {
    if (servicesConnected()) {
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, currentLocation));
    }
}

public void startUpdates(View v) {
    mUpdatesRequested = true;
    if (servicesConnected()) {
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }
}

public void stopUpdates(View v) {
    mUpdatesRequested = false;
    if (servicesConnected()) {
        stopPeriodicUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.connected);
    if (mUpdatesRequested) {
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.disconnected);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
     * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
     * services activity that can resolve error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {

            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                    LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        // If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the user with
        // the error.
        showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.location_updated);
    mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, location));
}

private void startPeriodicUpdates() {
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    mConnectionState.setText(R.string.location_requested);
}

private void stopPeriodicUpdates() {
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    mConnectionState.setText(R.string.location_updates_stopped);
}

private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
            this, LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
    if (errorDialog != null) {
        ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
        errorFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
    }
}

public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private Dialog mDialog;

    public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        super();
        mDialog = null;
    }

    public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDialog;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
```

is the callback which is called when the location changes. So, this should be put in your service so that it is able to receive the updates.

Comment: Thanks. What about the startPeriodicUpdates? I want that when app opens the periodic updates should start running unless user decidesto stop them.

Comment: Yes, your service must register to receive the updates as well. Also, when the service is destroyed, you must stop receiving the updates. Both the snippets would go in the definition of the service.

Comment: Please could you help me with code. I am trying many options but still unable to finish it

Comment: Okay this is what I have tried. I put all this in service by removing fragment activity and making it a service and making the necessary changes but then it give me null pointer exception saying the service cannot start. What should I do?

Comment: What is the exact exception that you get? Maybe the LogCat would be helpful. Anyway, I think this is how you should go about it. Have an Activity, inside whose onCreate() you start the service. And then register the service for the location updates. Should work from POV.

Comment: That is brilliant! Great! Good luck ahead! Cheers! :)